# Does request.body require rewind before read with Rails 4 and content-type application/json or is there a new approach?

Tags: json, rack, ruby-on-rails-4

When I post data to a Rails 4 application with Content-Type: "application/x-www-form-urlencoded" I can get the body of the request with request.body.read

However, when I post data with Content-Type "application/json", request.body.read is blank unless I call request.body.rewind first.

Two questions:

1.)  How do I get the raw request body without calling rewind on the stream first?

2.)  Is it possible to stop Rails (or Rack) parsing the JSON in the request body when the client sends content-type application/json

Note that in Rails 3, like Rails 4 the parsed JSON is available in params, but request.body.read does not require rewind first.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This [is indeed a bug](https://github.com/rails/rails/issues/11402). The fix has been integrated into master and should presumably pop up in 4.0.1.

Comment: thanks! been banging my head against the wall for a while now.

Comment: Woah, sorry for late acceptance! I'd forgotten about this question!

Answer (score 2):

Use request.env instead of request.body.read.

Comment: It seems these provide very different outputs.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like it might be a bug in ActionDispatch::ParamsParser.
Putting the following in config/application.rb seemed to fix it

```
config.middleware.delete ActionDispatch::ParamsParser
```